# Make word work with html tags

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-word

I Have a wysiwyg on a site, and it saves text to a database in straight text, but that comes with it's tags, so I have data that looks like

`<p><strong>Hello World</strong></p>`

In an sql server database. I can put that data 1:1 into a word file fine, but I'm curious as to if there is a way to convert those tags, without having to program something myself to do it, because that's proving to be more then a challenge.

I'm working on this in vb.net so if the answer supplied could relate to that, that would be a bonus. Thank you.

TLDR: **How do I take wysiwyg text from an sql server database, to MS-word using vb.net?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Save formatted text as HTML file
- Open html file using Word
- Save opened file as .docx

This will make the Word to pick up all formatting without actually showing tags. It’s not an ideal solution but it will definitely work.

Now sure if you already have the code to manipulate word docs, if not I suggest using [Open XML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) vs office interop assemblies

Answer (score 0):

Put your HTML string into a variable, like this:

```
Dim htmlAsString As String = valueFromDatabase
```

Then apply this regular expression:

```
Regex.Replace(htmlAsString, "<(.|\n)+?>", String.Empty)
```

Comment: Won't this just erase the tag? I need it to be bold, if there is a strong tag.

Comment: Yes, I thought you wanted to get rid of the markup tags, you want to convert them? What is the mapping logic?

Comment: Mapping logic? I'm not sure what you mean. I want it to be 1:1 what the wysiwyg shows, to what the word document would show.


Currently my program to do this is a little shaky I basically do a split like the Dim splitByTags() As String = Split(wysiwygText, "<") and then instr for end tags, then set a flag if it's bold, or emphasised or what not. Then depending on the flags set, I print out the appropriate font.